# An epimorphism in $\text{Grp}$ without right inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Exercise 8.24 in [Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf) asks us to find an epimorphism in $\text{Grp}$ without right inverses.

I happen to know that epimorphisms in $\text{Grp}$ are surjective, so we need a surjective $G\xrightarrow{\phi}G'$ without right inverses. But $G'\cong G/\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$, so in a sense we need a $G/\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ that cannot be realised as a subgroup of $G$.

I tried something but failed. Can someone give a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to play a bit with the quaternion group and check which possible subgroups and quotients it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quaternion Group $Q_8$ has a center of order $2$, and $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is isomorphic to the Klein $V$ group.  However every subgroup of $Q_8$ of order $4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the epimorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_{2},\phi(n)=n \pmod 2$.

Comment: But this one has an right inverse. I guess we cannot find what we need in abelian groups.

Comment: No, it does not have a right inverse (since the integers does not contain any element of order $2$, and any right inverse must be injective).

Comment: In fact, surjections between cyclic groups provide lots of examples.