# Smallest group with a derived series of length 2, 3 and 4

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

What are the smallest group with a derived series of length 2, 3 and 4?. I know that for n=2 the answer is S3 because that's the smallest metabelian non-abelian group. Could you help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Check small order known groups, say $$1\lhd V\lhd A_4\lhd S_4$$

Comment: Yes, that's a derived series of length four. Should I check that there aren't any groups that |G|<4! with a derived series of such length?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the smallest groups of derived lengths 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 respectively have orders 6, 24, 48, 432, and 1296 respectively.

The smallest group with derived length 2 is symmetric group on 3 points, $S_3$.

The smallest groups with derived length 3 are the symmetric group on 4 points, $S_4$, and the group of $2\times2$ matrices of determinant 1 with entries from a field with 3 elements, $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$.

The smallest groups with derived length 4 are the group of $2\times2$ matrices of nonzero determinant with entries from a field with 3 elements, $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$, and the so-called [fake GL(2,3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_octahedral_group) from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328175/examples-of-nonabelian-groups/329101#329101).

The smallest group with derived length 5 is the group of affine transformations $$ \operatorname{AGL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) = \left\{ \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} a & b & e \\ c & d & f \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right] : a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, ad-bc \neq 0 \right\} $$

The smallest groups with derived length 6 are three non-split extensions of $ \operatorname{AGL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ by a non-central, cyclic, normal subgroup of order 3. One of these is $\Gamma U_3(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, the split extension of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ acting on an extraspecial group of order 27 and exponent 3; the other two are nonsplit.

An exploration of a similar problem (where instead of group order, the number of prime factors is consider, so 2, 4, 5, 7, and 8 respectively) is in Glasby (1986, 2005).

- Glasby, S. P.
  “The composition and derived lengths of a soluble group.”
  J. Algebra 120 (1989), no. 2, 406–413.
  MR[989905](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=989905)
  DOI:[10.1016/0021-8693(89)90204-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(89)90204-4)
- Glasby, S. P.
  “Solvable groups with a given solvable length, and minimal composition length.”
  J. Group Theory 8 (2005), no. 3, 339–350.
  MR[2137974](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2137974)
  DOI:[10.1515/jgth.2005.8.3.339](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/jgth.2005.8.3.339)