Lifting every degree n projective representation to a linear representation of a Schur covering group in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$
$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $ G $ be a finite subgroup of $ \GL(n, \mathbb{C}) $ (and to nail things down a little more also suppose that $ G $ is irreducible in this natural representation). Let $ [G] $ be the corresponding subgroup of $ \PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $.
For every degree $ n $ projective irrep $ \rho $ of $ [G] $ does there exist a subgroup $ \tilde{G} $ of $ \GL(n, \mathbb{C}) $ such that $ \tilde{G} $ is a Schur cover of $ [G] $ and moreover $ \rho $ lifts to a linear irrep $ \tilde{\rho} $ of $ \tilde{G} $?
This can be viewed as a question in two parts.
(1) If $ [G] $ is an irreducible finite subgroup of $ \PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ does there always exist a Schur cover $ \tilde{G} $ of $ [G] $ that is a subgroup of $ \GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $? (2) Can any degree $ n $ projective irrep of $ [G] $ be lifted to a linear irrep of some such Schur cover of $ [G] $?
This seems to be true for $ n=2 $, where the only irreducible finite subgroups of $ \PGL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ are the dihedral groups $ Dih(n) $ of order $ 2n $ (with Schur covers $ Dih(2n) $ and $ Dic(n) $, both subgroups of $ \GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ ), and then $ A_4\cong \PSL(2,3) $ (with unique Schur cover the binary tetrahedral subgroup of $ \GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $, isomorphic to $ \SL(2,3) $ ), $ S_4 \cong \PGL(2,3) $ (with two Schur covers: $ \GL(2,3) $ and also the binary octahedral subgroup of $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $), $ A_5\cong \PSL(2,5) $ (with unique Schur cover the binary icosahedral subgroup of $ \GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $, isomorphic to $ \SL(2,5) $).
Side note showing that $ \GL(2,3) $ really is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $ \GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $:
let $ S= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix} $, $ H= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $. Then
$$
\langle\overline{\zeta_8} S, iH\rangle
$$
is a the binary octahedral subgroup of $ \SU(2) $. While
$$
\langle\zeta_8 S, H\rangle
$$
is the $ \GL(2,3) $ subgroup of $ \SU^{\pm 1}(2) $, the groups of unitary matrices with determinant $ \pm 1 $. (shout out to this excellent answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3670522/724711 which sort of inspired this choice of generators)

The answer to (1) is no if the Schur Multiplier of $[G]$ is not cyclic. I think the answer to(2) is yes.

@DerekHolt what do you mean by "the answer to (2) is yes"? Like does that mean that the Schur multiplier being cyclic is the only obstruction and if $ [G] \subset PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ has cyclic Schur multiplier then there always exist Schur cover $ \tilde{G} $ in $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ lifting any degree n projective rep? And as for your point about needing Schur multiplier cyclic that is a really good point I should have realized that would be important, I'll look in GAP for a specific counterexample with like maybe $ PSL(3,4) $? What are some small groups with non-cyclic Schur multiplier?

Yes $G={\rm SL}(3,4)$, $[G]={\rm PSL}(3,4)$ with $n=15$ gives a counterexample. There are probably smaller ones.

$GL = G\cdot L$ so your $\LaTeX$ is unreadable.

@DerekHolt Ah ok so if I understand you correctly then you are saying that (2) is correct in the sense that every degree n projective irrep of [G] arise from a linear irrep of some stem extension $ \tilde{G} $ of [G] with $ \tilde{G} $ a subgroup of $ PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $. However these subgroups of  $ PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ that are stem extensions of [G] may not be Schur covering groups (i.e. they may not be stem extensions with the maximal size among all finite groups).

And then the counter example you are suggesting for (1) is that $ PSL(3,4) $ is a subgroup of $ PGL(15,\mathbb{C}) $ but the Schur cover of $ PSL(3,4) $ cannot be a subgroup of $ GL(15,\mathbb{C}) $ since the Schur multiplier of $ PSL(3,4) $ is not cyclic
