# I want to read the 10,000 page paper on Classification of Finite Simple Groups?

Tags: group-theory, research

I want to read the **entire** 10,000 page paper on Classification of Finite Simple Groups, however, I cannot find a copy anywhere on the internet.

> For the past 3 years of my life, I have been working on a *marvelous* theory, but I ran into a few problems which could not be solved with regular math. **It turns out; Group theory is the key to my problems!** And so, I am happy to dedicate however long I need to studying groups at the highest level possible.

**Math Exchange Question: Can someone please link me to where I can get the entire paper?** I simply cannot find it anywhere else, and you guys here at math.stackexchange.com are sooo smart!! & you guys must know where I can find it!

Also, if you guys can link me to other resources to learn Group Theory.

Comment: Lol, no you don't. But [this](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.ams.org/bull/2001-38-03/S0273-0979-01-00909-0/S0273-0979-01-00909-0.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi4i6jC45jpAhWKX80KHSLTBO0QFjAPegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw36o4hzhdN_sBggDG7Ojz92) could be a good read.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber hii! Thank you for the link, I'll read it! (although I still am ambitious to read the entire paper!) edit:also please upvote if you can pleaseee!

Comment: The Classification of Finite Simple Groups is not a single paper. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#Second-generation_classification

Comment: @lhf Yes, it is a series of papers, where can I find them all in order? For something so important to math, this should be easy to find, but its not.

Comment: You don't want to read the papers; you want to read the distillation of the papers as they have come to be understood. The series of books by Solomon et al, still in progress, would be the way to go. [Here's some of them from the AMS bookstore](https://bookstore.ams.org/~searchResults?searchMode=advanced&context=-2&lang=&searchParam-Title=Classification&searchParam-AuthorsSearch=Solomon&?page=0)

Comment: @Arturo Ahhhh! I didn't know know about the Solomons from 2018. I've been out of the game too long. That's great news.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Yes, he re-started them when he retired, and has gotten a few out; there is also some ongoing work with Aschbacher, Lynd, and others to try to use fusion systems as the basis for the “next generation” proof, but that is still a ways off.

Comment: @Arturo Yeah, I do remember Aschbacher doing that. I read some of his book about it the summer after undergrad but never got to where I could use fusion for anything.

Comment: Related MathOverflow question is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114943).

Answer (score 6):

The thing about the Classification "paper" is that it is not one paper, it is a lot of papers. Like, more than a thousand. You *can* find multi-volume compilations of these papers in some academic libraries but really there is probably no *worse* way to learn about the classification than trying to read those.

To be clear, the papers weren't written after the fact, when everybody already had a good understanding of the theory and where it was going. They were written during the decades long process of discoveries, without any of the authors knowing that there even would be a full classification. The result is that they are very meandering and technically complicated, often excessively so. There has been a movement in recent years to simplify the classification theorem, now that we have a much better picture of the field, but it isn't done yet, and to my knowledge they have not released any intermediate volumes lately (EDIT: [I'm wrong](https://bookstore.ams.org/~searchResults?searchMode=advanced&context=-2&lang=&searchParam-Title=Classification&searchParam-AuthorsSearch=Solomon&?page=0)). In fact, there probably isn't anyone in the world who has read every part of the original theorem fully. It is just too big and too messy.

If what you want is to understand the details of the results of the classification, (i.e. the groups,) then, after learning the fundamentals of finite group theory, the direction to go is to read a book about finite simple groups. There is a good one by Robert Wilson. You can find reasonably good summaries online if you are only looking for a broad sub-research level understanding. This is just not a topic where you want to go directly to the primary source material.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer @AlexanderGruber <3 Im going to check out Robert Wilson, and you're probably right I shouldn't go directly to the source material.

Comment: I checked out your profile, and you seem to know alot about group theory!! You're very smart!!! Do you have discord or an email so I can talk to you incase I have any questions? Please... <3

Comment: I don't have discord but you can ping me in math.SE's chat. I'm around frequently.

Comment: Also you may want to check out [my (long) answer on nonabelian finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328175/examples-of-finite-nonabelian-groups/329101#329101) if you'd like to get a general sense of what's out there.