# Could you provide me with an example of a group which has elements $a, b$ and $c$ such that the order of $abc$ is different from the order of $acb$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, symmetry

I have tried messing with different symmetries and permutations but I am definitely stuck. What is the catch? Do I need to consider shapes that are more than 2 dimensional? Do I need to consider interactions between multilpe objects?

How does one arrive at such group, and what does it represent?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking for a group who *only* has $a,b,c$?  Or are you asking for a group who has elements $a,b,c$ among possibly many others?  These two questions give different results.  All groups of order three are abelian.  There exist nonabelian groups of order greater than 3 (*the smallest example being of order 4*).  [See examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328175/examples-of-finite-nonabelian-groups).

Comment: Choose b and c so that they don’t commute and then take a the inverse of bc.

Comment: Do you further want the group to be the group of symmetries of a shape?

Answer (score 4):

You were already on the right track with permutations, but didn't try enough.

Take the symmetric group $S_3$ and let $a=(23)$, $b=(12)$ and $c=(123)$. Then
$$
abc=(23)(12)(123)=(132)(123)=(1),
$$
but
$$
acb=(23)(123)(12)=(13)(12)=(123).
$$
So $abc$ has order $1$, whereas $acb$ has order $3$.

Comment: thank you very much ♥. may God bless you.